# Different results of a double integral before and after change of variables

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to plot the function `gcart`, defined as follows:

```
a = 0.397;
b = 36 10^-9;
fcart[x_, y_, t_, y0_] := b y/(x^2 + a^2 y^2) (1 - Cos[2 Sqrt[x^2 + a^2 y^2] t])/2 E^(-b^2 x^2 - b^2 (y - y0)^2);
gcart[t_, y0_] := NIntegrate[fcart[x, y, t, y0], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}];

data1gcart = ParallelTable[{t, gcart[t*10^-9, 12 10^6]}, {t, 0, 200, 1}];
data2gcart = ParallelTable[{t, gcart[t*10^-9, 120 10^6]}, {t, 0, 200, 1}];

ListPlot[{data1gcart, data2gcart}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 4.5}}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

[image: cartesian-coordinate result]

But, with the following variable change:

```
x = r/b Cos[θ] 
y = r/b Sin[θ]
```

`gcart` becomes `gpol`:

```
fpol[r_, θ_, t_, y0_] := (E^(-b^2 y0^2) Sin[θ])/(Cos[θ]^2 + a^2 Sin[θ]^2) (1 - Cos[2 r/b Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2 + a^2 Sin[θ]^2] t])/2 E^(-r^2 + 2 b r y0 Sin[θ]);
gpol[t_, y0_] := NIntegrate[fpol[r, θ, t, y0], {r, 0, ∞}, {θ, 0, 2 π}];
data1gpol = ParallelTable[{t, gpol[t*10^-9, 12 10^6]}, {t, 0, 200, 1}];
data2gpol = ParallelTable[{t, gpol[t*10^-9, 120 10^6]}, {t, 0, 200, 1}];
ListPlot[{data1gpol, data2gpol}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 4.5}}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
```

Theoretically `gpol == gcar`; by drawing the function `gpol` I should get the same graph as before. However, I get a different graph from the first one.

[image: polar-coordinate result]

Please help me find the cause or mistake that made this difference. Does this difference have an explanation?